# asp.net mvc browser compatability - which browser to design for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cross-browser

All my previous web development has been IE-only.  But in my current project, I may have a choice in which browser to design for.  My question is, which browser should I choose?  A quick google search revealed that Chrome adheres to the HTML standard most closely, so at first I thought I should pick Chrome.  But then I wondered if IE may be a better choice because maybe MVC's generated HTML is made to be IE-compatible.

Does ASP.Net MVC4/razor generate HTML that adheres to the HTML standard, or HTML that works in IE?  I understand I have much more control over the generated HTML with MVC compared to regular ASP.Net, but there is still some stuff being generated for me, such as Html.EditorFor(...)

So, if you could choose which browser your users would use for an ASP.Net MVC 4 project, which would you choose and why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good part of mvc, it's that you have fully control the html generated, so you can create your own markup, javascript and css properly to support any browser, or all the browser. So at the end it doesn't matter the mvc framework, what is important is the html that you created

Comment: But what about functions like Html.BeginForm or Html.DisplayNameFor? If you are using these, (which I am), then _some_ HTML is generated by MVC.  Isn't it possible there could be browser compatibility issues with this HTML?

Comment: No, because is html standard, also this are fully customize, by templates, scaffolding, EditorTemplates and DisplayTemplates